# input appears smaller than select but have same padding

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a input and a select option element next to each other. Both elements have a padding of 15px, but the input is a bit smaller than the select element. Do you know why? In chrome works fine.

[image]

Here is a example: https://jsfiddle.net/4bf50bt0/.

html:

```
<form class="Banner__search_form">

  <input type="text" value="Search">
  <select>
    <option selected>Title</option>
  </select>

  <select>
    <option selected>Subtitle</option>
  </select>


</form>
```

css:

```
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}


input,
select,
textarea,
button {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;

}

select,
input,
button {
  border: 0;
  appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Banner__search_form{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a common fixed height for them, fo example:

```
input,
select,
textarea,
button {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5em;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hL614er9/